# React Native TabBarIOS.Item Center icon

Tags: ios, react-native, tabbar

I'm trying to make a React Native application which has a TabBar on its iOS side. I don't want any title to button (like "Blue Tab" and "History") and I would like to center vertically the Person icon on the right.

[image: TabBarIOS]

Currently I'm using the code available in the [example](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tabbarios.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay I've just found how to do it :

In the TabBarIOS.Item props I removed :

```
title:"User"
```

And I just had to set the title as empty :

```
title=""
```

[image: lol]

Comment: Thank you! Been trying to figure this out for a while.

Answer (score 1):

To align vertically you can set (flex: 1,) flexDirection: 'row' in styles. Here is an article which helped me with aligning with flexbox in react-native, hope it will help you too :) http://moduscreate.com/aligning-children-using-flexbox-in-react-native/

Comment: Thanks ! It's a good tutorial but it didn't solve my problem. I've posted the answer above. :)